# ubuntu upstart never killing my process

Tags: ubuntu, upstart, signals

I have a simple bash script:

```
echo "Starting"
function sigint {
   echo "sigint"
}

function sigterm {
   echo "sigterm"
}

trap sigterm SIGTERM
trap sigint SIGINT

while true
do
  sleep 2
  echo "-"
done
```

I launch this script with upstart using this config file:

```
description "start trapper"
kill timeout 1

script
  ./home/ubuntu/trapper.sh >> /home/ubuntu/log.txt
end script

post-stop script
  echo "finished" >> /home/ubuntu/log.txt
end script
```

When I start it, with upstart, I can monitor the output of it in `/home/ubuntu/log.txt`. The problem is, when I stop my job, I see sigterm is sent to my program (it prints it), I then directly see "finished" (which is written in the post-stop script), but I still see "-" printed every 2 seconds ...

What happens is that upstart never send SIGKILL to my script, even if it says that stop succeeded (since it enters in the post-stop script).

Any help would be great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sending the SIGKILL to the shell most likely. Try adding `exec` before the `./home/ubuntu/trapper.sh`.